# Flexbox layout and background issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox, web-deployment

While developing new website for our client (he delivered design and insisted on using flexbox), we've come to element that looks like this (the "Samochody Peugeot" section with 2 little boxes at right):

[image]

Grid starts at text in left box, and ends at end of image in right boxes. The only real solution that we can find is to create the gray background using absolute positioned :before pseudo-element, but it seems pretty hacky.

At bigger widths the gray bg should expand to left, but everything else should stay in grid.

Is there any better way to achieve this kind of layout than using :before?

```
 <section class="boxes">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="boxes__box">
        <h3>Samochody<br/>PEUGEOT</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <a class="btn" href="">Przejdź do strony</a>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes__box-holder">
        <div class="boxes__box boxes__box--small">
            <h3>PONAD 20 LAT<br/>DOŚWIADCZENIA</h3>
            <a class="btn" href="">O firmie</a>
        </div>
        <div class="boxes__box boxes__box--small">
            <h3>POZNAJ NASZE<br/>USŁUGI</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <a class="btn" href="">Przejdź do strony</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

    .boxes {
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }

  &__box {
    width: 68%;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    &:first-child:before {
      content: '';
      height: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
      right: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
    }
  }

  &__box-holder {
    width: 32%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add HTML/CSS code, please.

Comment: Added html/css code

Comment: When you say _"At bigger widths the gray bg should expand to left, but everything else should stay in grid."_, then I can't see any other options, besides adding an extra element in the markup, which would be worse. In situations like this, I _love_ the pseudo elements, as they are to me nothing more than a really clever CSS property, and IMHO not hacky at all and perfectly suited to do just that.

Comment: As a comparison, you could restructure the layout, and make the "grid" cover full page and then use _padding/margin/max-width_ to keep the "box" not take full width on wider screens.